# How do I encode/decode a fetch URL/JSON using javascript and flask

Tags: javascript, flask, fetch, decode, encode

This is in reference to dynamically change options in a list by another list. Unfortunately, it all works except if the project name has a " or a #. Eg. Project name: '10" Centerline #3 Pipe'

I am a newbie to this and I have been cut/paste (learning) as I go along. If someone can help, it will be great. I am seen some things about escaping and encoding URI stuff but not sure where to put it in. The other problem is just understanding what happens past the onchange event.

I can get the list of project names from a previous list and it shows up in my HTML page. However, when I select the choices that have a ( " ) or a ( # ), the next populated list breaks.

Thanks in advance. I really, really appreciate the time if someone puts in a response.

Here is the javascript portion:

```
project_name_select.onchange = function(){
project_name = project_name_select.value;
fetch('/sr/new/project/' + project_name).then(function(response){
    response.json().then(function(data) {
        var areaHTML = '<option value="See List">Select Area</option>';

        for (var state of data.project_area) {
            areaHTML += '<option value="' + state.project_area + '">' + state.project_area + '</option>'
        }

        project_area_select.innerHTML = areaHTML;
    });
});
```

}

Here is the flask portion:

```
@surveys.route("/sr/new/project/<get_project_name>")

def project(get_project_name):
project_dict, dict_type = choice_project_dict(get_project_name)

project_areaArray = []
for proj in project_dict:
    ownerObj = {}
    ownerObj['id'] = proj['company_name']
    ownerObj['owner_company'] = proj['company_name']
    ownerArray.append(ownerObj)

return jsonify({'project_area': project_areaArray})
```

Comment: JS note: `then` chains, so don't use `fetch(...).then(function(response){ response.json().then(function(data) {...}`, chain properly: `fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then(data => { ... });`. Also stop using strings with `+` concatenation, and all the bugs that can introduce, and instead use modern templating strings: ```areaHTML = `${areaHTML}<option value="${state.project_area}">${state.project_area}</option>`;``` etc.

Comment: I was able to figure out the # sign... by fetch('/sr/new/project/' + encodeURIComponent(project_name)).

Comment: thanks Mike... I was watching older youTube videos/posts on how to do stuff. I only started learning javascript 3 weeks ago. I understand the $ sign now :-)

Comment: still not working with the " though... sigh... have tried project_name = project_name1.replace(/"/g, '%22') and nada.

Comment: So simplify you're problem: either something's wrong in the JS, or something's wrong in flask, or both. If both: you're going to have to pick only one of those. So first see if the JS is doing the wrong thing: your code triggers when `project_name_select` changes (note: you want to use 21 year old, instead of 22 year old. JS here: don't use `onchange = ...` but use `addEventListener("change", ...)` instead =), so start testing if what you get, is what you _should_ get: open dev tools, look at the network tab, and see if that `fetch` happens. If so, `console.log(data)` to see its content.

Comment: Basically, run through the [mcve] exercise so you know which parts of the code _don't_ contribute to your problem, so that you can then focus on the part(s) that _do_.